# Universal cover of $2$-dimensional CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X$ be a $2$-dimensional CW complex constructed as follows : Starts with a circle $S^1$, adjoin two $2$-cells $e_i,i = 1,2$ to $S^1$ by maps $f_i:\partial (e_i)\to S^1$ of degree $6$ and $8$ respectively. I want to calculate $\pi_2(X)$ by finding the universal cover $\tilde{X}$ of $X$. There's some similar post [Calculating $\pi_2(X\cup_\alpha e_\alpha)$ using Hurewics theorem and covering spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4160070/854335) but the answer uses some kind of *Fox differentiation*. Is there some easier way to see the universal cover of this space $X$?

In Hatcher Example 1.35, it describes the universal cover of $X_{m,n}$ which is a cylinder $S^1\times I$ via with identification $(z,0)\sim (e^{2\pi i/m}z,0)$ and $(z,1)\sim (e^{2\pi i/n}z,1)$. But I don't think this space is same as $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Regard the original $S^1$ as being formed from a single $0$-cell $*$ and a single $1$-cell $u'$ with lift $u$ in $\tilde{X}$. Let $x$ denote the image of a generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$in $\pi_1(X)$.

Then \begin{eqnarray*}\partial (e_1)&=&u(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)=3u(1+x),\\ \partial (e_2)&=&u(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)=4u(1+x).
\end{eqnarray*}

Here we use the order of $x$ is hcf$(6,8)=2$.  To visualise these boundary maps, consider the lift of the cells $e_1,e_2$ in the universal cover of $X$:

[image]

Free Fox differentiation is just a generalisation of this method for calculating the boundaries.

Now we have \begin{eqnarray*}\pi_2(X)&=&\pi_2(\tilde{X})=H_2(\tilde{X})\\&=&\{e_1 a+ e_2b\in \mathbb{Z}[x]^2|\,\, 3(1+x)a+4(1+x)b=0\}
\\&=&\{e_1 a+ e_2b\in \mathbb{Z}[x]^2|\,\, (1-x)|3a+4b\}
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus $\pi_2(X)$ is generated over $\mathbb{Z}$ freely by $$4e_1-3e_2, \quad e_1(1-x),\quad e_2(1-x).$$

Comment: I don't understand $\partial(e_1) = u(1+x+\cdots+x^5) = 3u(1+x)$ both equation and notation. Why suddenly addition and multiplication?

Comment: @barista Addition here is adding the six sides of the hexagon, to get its boundary.  However as this hexagon lies in the universal cover, there is a group action on its cells.  The multiplication is the action of the fundamental group of $X$ on the cells of $\tilde{X}$.  For example, if $u$ is the $1$-cell going from $*$ to $*x$, then $ux$ is the $1$-cell going from $*x$ to $*x^2$.